Error al importar una imagen en servidor
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación ASP.NET Core y tengo un endpoint para cargar imágenes. En mi entorno local, todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando despliego la aplicación en el servidor de producción, recibo un error 404 al intentar cargar una imagen.
Aquí está mi código del controlador:
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadLogo(Guid id, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("A file has not been provided.");
    }
    
    var eventEntity = await _context.Events.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    if (eventEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound(new { eventId = id, message = "Event not found" });
    }

    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string parentDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, ".."));
    var productFolder = _config["EnvironmentSettings:productFolder"] ?? "EventsManagementSystem";
    string rootPath = Path.Combine(parentDirectory, productFolder, "wwwroot", "images", "events");
    
    if (!Directory.Exists(rootPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath);
    }

    var fileName = $"{id}.jpg";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    eventEntity.Logo = $"/images/events/{fileName}";
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(new { message = "Logo successfully uploaded", logoPath = eventEntity.Logo });
}

Lo que he verificado:

He confirmado que el servidor tiene acceso al directorio donde se guardan las imágenes.
He revisado los registros y no veo errores relacionados con la carga de imágenes.
El endpoint funciona en local, pero al intentar usarlo en el servidor, me da un error 404.
¿Qué podría estar causando este problema en el servidor?

Agradezco cualquier orientación o solución que puedan ofrecer. 


Puedes anexar tu Startup.cs?, o valida que tengas UseStaticFiles().

Saludos. En eventEntity.Logo = $"/images/events/{fileName}"; tienes una ruta absoluta y no relativa (si tu sitio esta en raiz así bien; pero si es como un sub/micro-sitio puede ser ahí el detalle); adicionalmente te sugiero verifiques la respuesta para que tomes el logoPath y veas que recibes; así sabras la ruta "que localiza" y la comparas con la esperada; si ese Ok(new {message:...[...] no se retorna entonces es dentro de tu código que falla. En tal caso agrega un try y retorna el error en productivo.

Concuerdo con lo que indica el comentario anterior, esa ruta no funcionara en el servidor ya que esta apuntando a cierta carpeta(tu pc loca) pero si en servidor no existe puede que te tire el error que no encuentra o la ruta no es valida(404), el try catch es tu mejor opcion.
